# Why isn't MinGW's find command printing all files on drive C:?

Tags: windows, mingw, msysgit

I'm using [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) (as packaged by [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) for Windows), and I'm trying to list all the files on my C drive. I would expect

```
find /c
```

to do this. However, this is not what I'm seeing (in an MinGW window):

```
$ find /c
 ...
/c/Program Files
/c/Program Files/7-Zip
/c/Program Files/7-Zip/7-zip.chm
...
/c/System Volume Information
find: /c/System Volume Information: Permission denied
/c/WINDOWS
/c/ZInstaller
```

Why are the files under `WINDOWS` and `ZInstaller` not showing up? If I find `/c/windows` or `find /c/ZInstaller`, all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [1.0.11 release](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=46827) specifically addresses this problem.  Make sure you using at least that version of msys.

Summary of relevant change:

> Added: 2008.07.21
>   Changes:
>       Fix bug #1791494: find not reporting all expected matches.

Comment: Thanks, I was just using the latest msysgit. I'll look at the 1.0.11 version.